# How to update a value using where clause in strapi 4

Tags: strapi

I have a collection type "Order" which has a field called order_id.

how to write a where clause to **update** the order where order_id is "1234", how to achieve this functionality in strapi 4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which approach you'd like to use, so:

- Here's the section in the docs using REST API: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest#update-an-entry
- Here's the section in the docs using the Entity Service API: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/entity-service/crud#update
- Here's the section in the docs using the Query Engine API: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/query-engine/single-operations#update